# Error in Apache Drill when doing JOIN between two large tables

Tags: sql, join, left-join, apache-drill

I'm trying to make a JOIN between two tables, one having 1,250,910,444 records and the other 385,377,113 records using the Apache Drill. 
However, after 2 minutes of execution, it gives the following error:

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: RESOURCE ERROR: One or more nodes ran out of memory while executing the query. Failure allocating buffer. 
Fragment 1:2 [Error Id: 51b70ce1-29d5-459b-b974-8682cec41961 on sbsb35.ipea.gov.br:31010] 
(org.apache.drill.exec.exception.OutOfMemoryException) Failure allocating buffer. io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.allocate():64 org.apache.drill.exec.memory.AllocationManager.():80 
org.apache.drill.exec.memory.BaseAllocator.bufferWithoutReservation():243 
org.apache.drill.exec.memory.BaseAllocator.buffer():225 org.apache.drill.exec.memory.BaseAllocator.buffer():195 
org.apache.drill.exec.vector.VarCharVector.allocateNew():394 org.apache.drill.exec.vector.NullableVarCharVector.allocateNew():239 
org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800$BatchHolder.():137 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800.newBatchHolder():697 
org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800.addBatchHolder():690 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800.addBatchIfNeeded():679 
org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800.put():610 org.apache.drill.exec.test.generated.HashTableGen1800.put():549 
org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.join.HashJoinBatch.executeBuildPhase():366 
org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.join.HashJoinBatch.innerNext():222 
org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():162 
org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():119 
org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next():109 
...
java.lang.Thread.run():748
```

Drill configuration information I'm using: planner.memory_limit = 268435456
The server I'm using has 512GB of memory.

Could someone suggest me how to solve this problem? Creating index for each table could be a solution? If so, how do I do this on Drill.

Answer (score 3):

1. Currently Apache Drill does not support indexing.
2. Your query fails during execution stage so planner.memory_limit won't take any effect.
3. Currently all you can do is allocate more memory:

   - make sure you have enough direct memory allocated in drill-env.sh;
   - use planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node option.
4. There is ongoing work in the community to allow spill to disk for the Hash Join 
   but it's still in progress (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6027).

Answer (score 1):

Use setting the planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node to the max possible.

ALTER SESSION SET 'planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node' = (some Value)

1. Make sure the parameter is set for this session.
2. check the DRILL_HEAP and DRILL_DIRECT_MAX MEMORY too.

Comment: The planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node is set to 4294967296; DRILL_HEAP  = `export DRILL_HEAP=${DRILL_HEAP:-"26G"}`; and DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY = `export DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=${DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY:-"102G"}`.

Comment: I changed the planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node = 4294967296 (4GB) to 8589934592 (GB). After that, I can not initialize Drill, because it gives the following error: `Error: Failed to start Drillbit built-in: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not deserialize "/tmp/drill/sys.options/planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node
.sys.drill "(state =, code = 0)`

Comment: You are running the drill locally or in another machine.

Comment: After all the research I have done for 6 months this is due to drill allocating the memory for each drillbit which is not sufficient for the drillbit to retrieve that part of the query as the data from the part of the query is very huge and it is due to max query memory per node.

Comment: And let me know about the tables you mentioned are those drill tables or normal text files.